# Take two at a time in a bash "for file in $list" construct

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have a list of files where two subsequent ones always belong together. I would like a for loop extract two files out of this list per iteration, and then work on these two files at a time (for an example, let's say I want to just concatenate, i.e. cat the two files).

In a simple case, my list of files is this:

```
FILES="file1_mateA.txt file1_mateB.txt file2_mateA.txt file2_mateB.txt"
```

I could hack around it and say

```
FILES="file1 file2"
for file in $FILES
do
    actual_mateA=${file}_mateA.txt
    actual_mateB=${file}_mateB.txt

    cat $actual_mateA $actual_mateB
done
```

But I would like to be able to handle lists where mate A and mate B have arbitrary names, e.g.:

```
FILES="first_file_first_mate.txt first_file_second_mate.txt file2_mate1.txt file2_mate2.txt"
```

Is there a way to extract two values out of $FILES per iteration?

Comment: This works in zsh, but sadly not in bash: `for a b in foo bar baz bing; do echo $a $b; done`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use an array for the list:

```
files=(fileA1 fileA2 fileB1 fileB2)
for (( i=0; i<${#files[@]} ; i+=2 )) ; do
    echo "${files[i]}" "${files[i+1]}"
done
```

Comment: What if the list is coming from a stream or another command instead of a predefined array?

Comment: @voutasaurus `while read first && read second` or something similar, depends on what you want to do if the number of elements is odd.

Answer (score 13):

You could read the values from a while loop and use xargs to restrict each read operation to two tokens.

```
files="filaA1 fileA2 fileB1 fileB2"
while read -r a b; do
    echo $a $b
done < <(echo $files | xargs -n2)
```

Comment: This is the least complicated and most flexible answer. Thanks, Fish.

Comment: Well, `echo $files | xargs -n2 your_command` would be much less complicated if `your_command` only needs two final positional arguments, but agreed that the `while read` gives you a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 10):

You could use xargs(1), e.g.

```
ls -1 *.txt | xargs -n2 COMMAND
```

The switch  -n2 let xargs select 2 consecutive filenames from the pipe output  which are handed down do the COMMAND

To concatenate the 10 files file01.txt ... file10.txt pairwise 
one can use

```
ls *.txt | xargs -n2 sh -c 'cat $@  > $1.$2.joined' dummy
```

to get the 5 result files

```
file01.txt.file02.txt.joined
file03.txt.file04.txt.joined
file05.txt.file06.txt.joined
file07.txt.file08.txt.joined
file09.txt.file10.txt.joined
```

Please see 'info xargs' for an explantion.

Comment: How do you do anything remotely complicated with the result when you have to put the whole output processing command in xargs?

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
park=''
for file in $files  # wherever you get them from, maybe $(ls) or whatever
do
  if [ "$park" = '' ]
  then
    park=$file
  else
    process "$park" "$file"
    park=''
  fi
done
```

In each odd iteration it just stores the value (in `park`) and in each even iteration it then uses the stored and the current value.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like one of those things `awk` is suited for

```
$ awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i+=2) if( i+1 <= NF ) print $i " " $(i+1) }' <<< "$FILES"
file1_mateA.txt file1_mateB.txt
file2_mateA.txt file2_mateB.txt
```

You could then loop over it by setting IFS=$'\n'

e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES="file1_mateA.txt file1_mateB.txt file2_mateA.txt file2_mateB.txt file3_mat
input=$(awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i+=2) if( i+1 <= NF ) print $i " " $(i+1) }' 

IFS=$'\n'
for set in $input; do
  cat "$set" # or something
done
```

Which will try to do

```
$ cat file1_mateA.txt file1_mateB.txt
$ cat file2_mateA.txt file2_mateB.txt
```

And ignore the odd case without the match.

Comment: Hey, just thought I'd share my two cents. You already have comparison with NF, so why not start with `i=2` and print `$(i-1) $i` instead of checking again? (Why even generate that sequence?)  `F="a1.txt b1.txt a2.txt b2.txt remove_me.txt"; while read a b F <<<$F && [[ ${#F} > 0 ]]; do echo "{$a, $b} ($F)"; done`

Comment: It works in my Bash. For your sequence, you might like messing around with `echo {1..10..2} {10..1..2}`, but unfortunately I can't get it to work dynamically like I intended, `echo {1..${#F}..2}` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform you string to array and read this new array by elements:

```
#!/bin/bash

string="first_file_first_mate.txt first_file_second_mate.txt file2_mate1.txt file2_mate2.txt"
array=(${string})
size=${#array[*]}

idx=0

while [ "$idx" -lt "$size" ]
do
    echo ${array[$idx]}
    echo ${array[$(($idx+1))]}
    let "idx=$idx+2"
done
```

If you have delimiter in string different from space (i.e. `;`) you can use the following transformation to array:

```
array=(${string//;/ })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
echo file1 file2 file3 file4 | while read -d ' ' a; do read -d ' ' b; echo $a $b; done
file1 file2
file3 file4
```

Or this, somewhat cumbersome technique:

```
echo file1 file2 file3 file4 |tr " " "\n" | while :;do read a || break; read b || break; echo $a $b; done 
file1 file2
file3 file4
```